# Since when is layering possible in Websites?

Tags: html, css

I'm asking because I remember a time when it wasn't possible 
to create a div box on another one, and I was wondering when was it introduced. 
It's probably a matter of CSS version, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [z-index CSS property,](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index) which introduced the 'z-axis' and the ability to stack elements, was introduced with CSS2.

CSS2 was [published by the W3C as a Recommendation in May 1998.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#CSS_2) So you're right -- it wasn't always possible, but it's been around for a while!

Comment: I remember learning HTML on about 1999/1998... since the books weren't updated the design was inside.. <font color="red" size="4"> text </font>

Answer (score 6):

Layers were first possible in Netscape 3 using the [`<layer>`](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/p/bltags_layer.htm) tag. This tag was proprietary to Netscape and was not supported by Internet Explorer. Support for it was abandoned in Netscape 6.

IE 4 used `<div>` tags and the `z-index` CSS property to create layers. That has since become standard.